# Canonical error(As Non www to www) through web config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have a website which is facing canonical issue.i want my website to move from non-www to www when ever i type my url for example abc.com to www.abc.com.i got a code but it is not working.

```
  <rewrite>
 <rules>
   <rule name="RedirectToWWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(\S+)\.com$" />
   </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}/{R:0}" />
   </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

as the error is:
rewrite doesnot belong to system.webServer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider a different approach:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!Request.Url.Host.StartsWith ("www") && !Request.Url.IsLoopback)
 {
  UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder (Request.Url);
  builder.Host = "www." + Request.Url.Host;
  Response.Redirect (builder.ToString (), true);
 }
}
```

This will however do a 302 redirect so a little tweak is recommended:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest (object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 if (!Request.Url.Host.StartsWith ("www") && !Request.Url.IsLoopback)
 {
  UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder (Request.Url);
  builder.Host = "www." + Request.Url.Host;
  Response.StatusCode = 301;
  Response.AddHeader ("Location", builder.ToString ());
  Response.End ();
 }
}
```

This one will return 301 Moved Permanently.

If you want to add it in **web.config** check this link http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/27/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www.aspx

Comment: where i need to place this method,please tell me complete description about it

Comment: There is global.asax file. In that you can see different types of methods.

Comment: now my url is coming as www.abc.com/home.aspx but i want only www.abc.com even when i redirect it from some other page(like from about us to home)than also it should show www.abc.com

Comment: Just set a break point in function. you can get the idea. Debug it

Comment: we want to remove /home.aspx from our url so for that what we need to do...please suggest a solution for it

Comment: Tell me one thing have you set particular page as a start up page ?

Comment: and also i have added your code to my home page and called that particular method at page load of home page

Comment: You have to add this code in global.asax page. No need to add in home page.

Comment: Ajay, i m still getting the same url as www.abc.com/home.aspx after applying ur procedure of global.asax

Comment: right click your project-> property. Select web tab. In Web Tab select "Specific Page" radio button and make sure the text block doesn't content any value.

Comment: dear ajay..i have a problem as when i first visit to my website i get a url as www.abc.com and when i visit to other page on our website and then click to home link my url get set as www.abc.com/home.aspx but i want it to be www.abc.com...so please provide me a solution for it ,will be really thankfull to you.